# Should sales/order/create/data.phtml have output the order_item_extra_info child?

Tags: adminhtml

I think I may have stumbled across a core defect, but not 100% sure.

Exhibit A:

```
<!-- adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml -->
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_data" template="sales/order/create/data.phtml" name="data">
    ...
    <block type="core/text_list" name="order_item_extra_info"></block>
</block>
```

Exhibit B:

```
<!-- adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml -->
No reference to order_item_extra_info to be found
```

What I'm trying to do in my particular case is to inject a template into this text list in order to inject some javascript that will run after the shipping address loads in the backend order creation routine.

So I've simply added `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_item_extra_info') ?>` to `data.phtml` but wanted to make sure this was a core fix and not a core hack.

Comment: I think you are right. This is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is, in fact, a core bug.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been working on this issue for the last couple of weeks to no real avail. Magento support hasn’t proved to be much use as they are

> “not able to fix this issue as it is more of an enhancement request, since there is no such definition in our native layouts for exactly that template”.

Simply adding `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_item_extra_info') ?>` to the bottom of `adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml` does in fact allow you to render custom forms at the bottom of the Order Creation page within the admin panel.

Here’s an example where I injected a simple “Hello World”.

[image: hello world working]

However, for some reason this also breaks the "Re-order" functionality and the template is rendered in an odd place on that page, right where you should be adding products instead.

[image: hello world in wrong place]

This looks a bit silly with "Hello World" popping up in the wrong place, but were I to replace this with a fully fledged form it would look mad and break a lot of functionality.

Seeing as this form is clearly not working (even with a core hack) I think the best approach is to create a new tab on the Order View page within the admin panel, and add your custom form element within there.

Your layout xml should look a bit like this:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>your_name.goes_here</name>
            <block>namespace_module/adminhtml_sales_order_whatever_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Then all you have to do is create a block (which I think defines it's template with a `$this->setTemplate` in the constructor) which `implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface` and `extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget`

At least with this method you can be a lot happier that you are not breaking vanilla functionality, and you are still able to add extra data to an admin panel order.